# how to make changes to /sys/module/*/parameters persistent?

Tags: fedora, kernel-modules

I recently had an issue where after boot, my keyboard would not work. I needed to plug it out and in again to use it.
The problem was that my usb went into autosuspend, which can be disabled with `echo -1 >/sys/module/usbcore/parameters/autosuspend`.

But now after some time working `/sys/module/usbcore/parameters/autosuspend` contains `2` again, I am suspecting this was caused by updating my kernel.

Is there a way to have this parameter not change with updates?
I read about loading the modules and providing the parameters in `/etc/modprobe.d` or `/etc/module-load.d` but I couldn't find syntax on how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not caused by updating your kernel -- it's simply caused by rebooting. `/sys` isn't a "real" filesystem on disk — it's direct access into kernel interfaces, but exposed as a virtual filesystem. As such, nothing is written anywhere that gets saved in a permanent way when you make changes to those files. (Or "files", I guess.)

As you read somewhere, you can provide the parameter on the kernel command line. In the case you've explained above, that'd be `usbcore.autosuspend=-1`

We have an [article on setting kernel command line arguments on Fedora Linux](https://fedoramagazine.org/setting-kernel-command-line-arguments-with-fedora-30/) on Fedora magazine. Short story:

```
 grubby --update-kernel=ALL --args="usbcore.autosuspend=-1"
```

and then it'll persist after a reboot (and all subsequent kernel upgrades).

Comment: It seems this wasn't the solution to my problem after all. Changing to a different USB socket did work, so I'm suspecting my socket is faulty......
However learned about Linux from your answer so still thanks a lot :)

Answer (score -1):

You should try `sudo dracut --force`. This will rebuild the initramfs and loads it upon boot.

**EDIT:** `dracut` basically rebuilds the initramfs/initrd for preloading block device modules, unpacks that archive into RAM disk, mounts and uses it as initial root file system.